# How to perform arithmetic on the individual digits of a number

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, task

There is a function that takes two arguments. The first argument is the number of digits in the number.
The second argument is the number itself. (5, 12345). Arguments will be passed in this format).
It is necessary to take the first and last digit of this number and add them. Then return the product of these new numbers.

Example solution ->

```
arguments(5, 12345)
(1+5)*(2+4)*3 = If the number of digits is odd
arguments(6, 123456)
(1+6)*(2+5)*(3+4) = If the number of digits is even
```

Here is the code that I wrote, for some reason it outputs NaN constantly, how to fix it and how to write conditions for the loop?

```js
var a = prompt("Number: ");
a = Array.from(a).map(i => Number(i));

if (a.length % 2 == 0) {
    result = (a[0] + a[a.length - 1]) * (a[1] + a[a.length - 2]) * (a[1] + a[a.length - 2]);
    alert(result);
} else {
    result = (a[0] + a[a.length - 1]) * (a[1] + a[a.length - 2]) * a[3];
    alert(result);
}
```

Comment: *"There is a function that takes two arguments."* - Your program only ever asks for one input?  *"for some reason it outputs NaN constantly"* - Not for me it doesn't.  If I enter `12345` I get a result.  Can you clarify what debugging you have done?

Comment: @David - entering a 5 digit number without the comma works but with the comma `4,1234` etc it fails

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius: Well, sure, because a comma isn't a number.  Perhaps the OP is confused about how to prompt for two different values?  Though one of the two isn't needed as it can be (and is, in the OP's code) inferred from the other.

Comment: Agreed it is easy enough to calculate the length and is simply adding a layer of complexity not required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a generic version of your solution.

Try like this:

```js
let a = prompt("Number: ");
a = Array.from(a).map((i) => Number(i));

const n = Math.floor(a.length / 2);
let answer = a.length % 2 === 1 ? a[n] : 1;

let i = 0;
while (i < n) {
  answer *= a[i] + a[a.length - (i + 1)];
  i++
}

alert(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with simple while loop.

```js
let argument = (Numberlength, num) => {

  let arr = [...(num + '')].map(Number)

  let i = 0;
  let j = Numberlength - 1; // last element or arr.length -1
  let product = 1;
  while (i <= j) {
    let sum = arr[i] + arr[j]
    if (i === j) { //  incase odd we only need to add one
      sum = arr[i];
    }
    product *= sum;
    i++;
    j--;
  }
  return product
}
console.log(argument(1, 12345)); // 1 
console.log(argument(2, 12345)); // 1 + 2 
console.log(argument(3, 12345)); // (1 + 3) * 2
console.log(argument(4, 12345)); // (1 + 4) * (2 + 3)
console.log(argument(5, 12345)); // (1 + 5) * (2 + 4) * 3
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

```
var a = prompt("Number: ");
a = Array.from(a).map(i => Number(I));
var result = 1;
var k = 0;
for (j = a.length - 1; j >= a.length / 2 ; j--) {
    result *= a[j] + a[k];
    k++;
}
if (a.length % 2 == 0) {
    alert(result);
} else {
    result *= a[k];
    alert(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this logic : (with process of mathematical operators apply)

```js
let str = "";

function check(len, num) {
  let numArray = Array.from(String(num), Number),
    temp = 1,
    result = 1;

  while (numArray.length != 0) {
    let first = numArray.shift();
    let last = numArray.pop();
    let checkIsAvailable = numArray[0];

    str = str + `(${first}`;

    if (last) {
      str += `+${last})`;
    } else {
      str += ")";
    }

    if (checkIsAvailable) {
      str += "*";
    }

    if (first == undefined) first = 0;
    if (last == undefined) last = 0;

    result = result * (first + last);
  }

  return result;
}

let sum = check(5, 1234567);

console.log(sum);

console.log(str);
```